# Undefined at beginning of concatenated characters

Tags: javascript, concatenation, undefined

I'm trying to write a script to do a simple letter shift, or caesar cipher; which works fine for the most part, except when the end result is produced, it is always headed with 'undefined'. I can't see where an undefined value would be included in the final result, except for where the variable is null until a value has been stored; but I see no way that could get past, or be remedied. The code I think is relevant follows, if any more is required, just ask.

```
for (var i=0;i<=len;i++) {
    wrkchar = txt.charAt(i);
    wrkasci = wrkchar.charCodeAt();
cypasci = wrkasci+shift;
}
cypchar = String.fromCharCode(cypasci);
if (endrslt==="") {
  endrslt = cypchar;
}
else {
  endrslt = endrslt+cypchar;
}
}
otpt.innerHTML = len+" "+txt+"</br>"+endrslt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out: I had defined it at the beginning of the function without a value, creating the variable without a value.